# Repair BAT file association (to make it start again)

Tags: batch-file

I am just hitting myself over the head right now. I wanted to change my "EDIT" setting of .BAT files to PsPad - instead I accidently changed the OPEN menu.

Now I was able to remove the entry using "[Defaults Program Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/)", a nice litte tool. But now I dont know which "default program" to select when doubleclick .BAT files. I tried CMD.exe, but maybe I need some option to make it run, it just opens the command line and does nothing at the moment :-(

Chris

Comment: try `cmd /c`​​​​

Comment: try cmd.exe "%1" infact adding to what farseeker says try /c or /k.. /k would make it stay open so cmd /k "%1"

Comment: yeah, that was it :-) cant give bounty if you only comment - so if you want, add it as answer. Damn, that was simple, but really hard to look at google for these search tearms (run, bat, batch)

Comment: for an answer using only Windows features, please see https://superuser.com/questions/1021219/windows-batch-file-not-running-when-i-double-click-how-to-restore-association-w/1269561#1269561

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My machine uses the command `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /c "%1" %*`

The /c is not necessary though.

As mentioned in the comments you have already figured this out though.