# Windows batch file not running when I double click, how do I restore the association with cmd.exe?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, batch, batch-file

Windows 8 64-bit. The user I'm logged in as has admin rights. When I open a cmd windows the window title even says "Administrator: cmd.exe".

So, I set my .bat file association to have the .bat file opened in Notepad++, and now I can't set it back to run the bat file when I double click on it. I've tried several web pages which told me to edit the registry to no avail.

When I do try to merge a .reg file into my PC, I get an error "You do not have permissions" or something. My user is not "administrator" but my user "chuck" does have admin rights. It always has.

1. I tried [this method](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html), the .reg file merged without error this time, but when I double click on a .bat file it still opens in Notepad++. I downloaded the file to change the .bat file assoc only. Do I have to restart the PC?
2. I also tried making the registry edits here: [click here](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1947165/open-batch-file-windows.html). It didn't work either.
3. The .bat file extension cannot be changed in the Associate File Extension with a Program in the Control panel. When I try to associate cmd.exe with a .bat file I get an error like "You cannot associate that program with this file."
4. I found [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/53948/how-do-i-restore-bat-files-as-executables) but there is no .bat file entry under FileExts. Also on this link I have no no UserChoice key to delete for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.b‌​at\UserChoice`.
5. Rebooted PC, I still have the same problem. I will make sure Notepad++ is not restoring associations with itself each time it runs. EDIT: As far as NPP preferences are concerned, it does not register .bat files.

Any more ideas? I have been dealing with this for 3 months off and on now.

NOTE: Some fixes for this problem work on Windows 7 but DO NOT work on Windows 8.

---

UPDATE: Fixed it. I had to

1. Make a shortcut to regedt32.exe on my desktop.
2. Right click shortcut and do "Run As Administrator", even though my user has admin rights.
3. Search the whole registry for the string "notepad" whereon I found the sneaky little thing here: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\\**Roaming**\OpenWith\FileExts\\.bat` and deleted the `UserChoice` item.
4. Reboot windows.

Comment: "Do I have to restart the PC? " Probably, haven't you tried that yet?

Comment: Yes I rebooted, it didn't help.

Comment: @Bulrush Did you read through this with the registry ownship part? [TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fc2ca91d-5509-4c9b-92a5-5af19375e361/lost-bat-file-association?forum=w7itprogeneral)

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE: Yes. I have no "user choice" in the registry path specified. The solutions that work for Windows 7 don't seem to work for Windows 8.

Answer (score 5):

Restoring cmd, bat and exe associations work differently from other file types.

To restore these, run CMD.EXE as Administrator, then:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6003]
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>assoc .bat=exefile
.bat=exefile

C:\Windows\system32>assoc .cmd=exefile
.cmd=exefile
```

That's it!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct, since the default association of .bat is batfile, not exefile. But this worked for me and nothing else. So definitely a good workaround.

Comment: Although this actually works as written it's not a good idea to do it this way as it builds a faulty mental model. `ASSOC` is the  command and `.bat` is the parameter. So it should be `assoc  .bat=..etc` and not `assoc.bat=...etc`. _But: cool! I didn't know about this particular CMD bug. ;-)_

Comment: Thank you. It worked well for me. It is simple and fast.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem on Windows 10.  I solved it by following the steps below.

1. run regedit with admin privilege. on Windows 10, open any Explorer window (i.e., file folder), press 'Alt-F S A' (without the quote nor the spaces), and PowerShell window will open.  type 'regedit', then return.  the regedit window will open.
2. go to \HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft.
3. search for '.bat', specifying that whole field must be the same.
   on my computer it happens to be at:
   \HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.bat
4. verify that there is a 'UserChoice', which specifies the editor or whatever you specified.
5. remove 'UserChoice'.
6. exit regedit.

Now double click on any .bat file and it should run.

I did not need to restart my PC, which runs Windows 10.

Comment: will someone please add a Windows-10 tag please?

Comment: doesn't work for Windows Server 2012

Comment: @user817540 at the end of regedit path, although you wrote "FileExts\.bat" it is rendered on browser as "FileExts.bat". Another \ may help. I could not edit it, as minimum edit character count is 6.

Answer (score 0):

**This assumes you are an administrator**

You can set associations from the command line start->run->enter 'cmd' (no quotes) and press enter

Then type

```
cmd /c assoc .bat
```

This will give you the filetype the OS *thinks* a .bat file is/does/whatever

```
cmd /c ftype batfile
```

This will give you the command which runs when you 'execute' the file - assuming that the first command returns '.bat=batfile' you need to set the association and you do so with this command

```
Ftype batfile="%1" %*
```

Comment: I did this and it didn't work though I haven't rebooted yet. Thank you.

Comment: Did it work after a reboot?

Comment: Rebooted, and it still didn't work. .BAT files are still associated with opening up in Notepad. I wonder if I have to make "Run" the default action instead of "Edit".

Comment: Sorry, .BAT files still open up in Notepad++ after reboot.