# Batch file does not run

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, batch

I wrote a simple `.bat` file that appends the string `"somethingnew"` infront of `.txt` files:

`for %%x in (*.txt) do ren "%%x" "somethingnew%%~nx"`

But when I run it from the command prompt (or when I double click it) it does nothing.

I found [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1021219/windows-batch-file-not-running-when-i-double-click-how-do-i-restore-the-associa) but there is no item called "UserChoice" in the registry and I checked that the `.bat` association is correct.

Thanks.

EDIT: Also, I've noticed that when I double click the file, the command prompt opens for a split second and then closes, and when I try to run the file through the command prompt, it runs but does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried your batch script.  It works, but it doesn't output anything showing it's working.  If you want confirmation it did something, add "pause" on another line.  Also, it renamed my txt files without adding .txt to the end of the filename.  Here's your updated code that should address both issues:

```
for %%x in (*.txt) do ren "%%x" "somethingnew%%~nx.txt"
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for the `pause` and for the `.txt` at the end. That was what messed up the previous code as I didn't notice that the files had changed file format when I had run a similar command. However, your code also renames the first file twice.

Comment: I created three new txt files, and they all get renamed correctly, but the first file gets renamed twice before the `pause`

Comment: Try renaming all of your `.txt` files to something other than "somethingnew.txt" and running the code again.  I just tried it and it worked fine.

Comment: Here is an image for clarification: https://ibb.co/mtj5cPZ

Comment: `1.txt` becomes `somethingnew1.txt`, then `2.txt` becomes `somethingnew2.txt`, then `somethingnew1.txt` becomes `somethingnewsomethingnew1.txt`

Comment: That's strange... Did you by chance forget to remove the old code before pasting the new code?  Try making a new batch script and paste the code I provided.

Comment: It's a new script. I don't know why it works on your pc but not on mine.

Comment: Try removing the pause from the script.

Comment: I removed it and it does the same thing.

Comment: Let's move this discussion to chat so we don't pollute the comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119383/discussion-between-salocor-and-zero-pancakes).